# Is it worth implementing C++ code through JNI in this application?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm developing a server application, and would like to harness the flexibility and (possible) speed increases C++ has to offer, by implementing the network code in C++. However, the base application has to be written in Java.

I'm aware of the possible reliability and debugging impact implementing JNI-code might have on the JVM. So I would like to know, would it be worth implementing such behavior in C++, or would the overhead caused simply not make it worth it?

Restriction: writing the application entirely in C++ is not an option.

**Edit:** I am a skilled (not very, but I can solve most tasks) C++ programmer, and I plan to use a library, do you have any suggestions?

Main criteria:

1. Speed
2. Raises the abstraction level
3. Event dispatched
4. Asynchronous (I will synchronize the code in Java before calling the C++ functions)
5. Has support for/is multithreaded)

Comment: If it's easier to develop the app in Java, doing that first is probably the best way to go about it.  After you have your application working, or working enough to run some use-case scenarios, profile it and see if it's a hindrance to have the networking in Java.

Comment: Why don't you write it in C++ and communicate it to the Java layer with Protobuff or Thrift

Comment: @Atreys +1 It is better to have a working solution that could be optimized later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not be worth it for the reasons you mentioned (related to overhead) and without getting into any c++/java wars about performance, there wouldn't be enough of it (performance) to impact the throughput of client/server type of calls.

In most client/server type of applications, the movement of data across the network itself and the application level processing will constitute the vast majority of your time.  Basically the amount of time spent in the servers network layer will be such a small percentage of the total time that performance benefits won't make enough of a difference.

Whether this balance holds true in your particular case, I cannot say since I don't know the nature of your application, but I would say it is the typical case.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is IO/bound, then optimising the CPU load is unlikely to make a significant difference. JNI itself also has overheads.

Answer (score -2):

I'm fairly certain that writing something as complicated as networking code in C++ instead of Java is going to be very time-consuming unless you have access to people who are already skilled C++ programmers.  If this is the kind of thing where you don't know C++ but heard it's faster, you're better off keeping everything in Java and focusing on your implementation.

Performance-wise C++ should be "faster" assuming that you implement any C++ modules in a sane fashion.  You'll note that "faster" was in quotes - I don't believe it's likely to make very much difference.

Comment: Depends on what level networking code you're writing.  The C networking APIs are equivalent to Java socket classes (only you pass the socket as a parameter, C-style OOP).  And there are plenty of C++ libraries that raise the level of abstraction, e.g. `boost::asio` provides event dispatch, `libcurl` for communicating with HTTP servers, etc.

Comment: @Ben You mean equivalent in speed?

Comment: @Oscar: No, I mean equivalent in complexity.  Pretty much any method in the socket class, I can name the C API that does the same thing.  The Java network classes are built on top of the C network APIs, so naturally there's a little bit of overhead.  Usually the overhead is small enough compared to the rest of the data processing that people choose Java for ease of coding and debugging, but OS calls are always going to be a little faster in C.

Comment: emphasis on the "little" faster, though.  there's not much chance at all that rewriting the networking in C is going to turn an unusably slow app into one that performs well.

Comment: The assumption that writing networking code n Java is somehow easier or faster than doing it in C++ is completely wrong. The more complex the solution, the easier to implement it in C++/

Comment: Erm, assuming one is at least as proficient in C++ as one is in Java, you might be right.  Situationally.

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev Networking code in Java is far simpler and shorter than the same thing expressed in C. Even just the InetAddress class saves you from all sorts of convolutions in the C code.

Comment: And you're all ignoring the overheads of JNI and any marshalling! I'm sure that JNI has a non-zero cost.

Comment: the JNI overhead isn't likely to be the cause of performance bottlenecks, though